# Javascript function not working for login

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create a very simple login form that requires the user to input a password and a username. If the user does not input a username or a password then i want an alert to pop up informing the user that he needs to input a username or a password and the page will not continue on to the welcome page. however this is not working......i dont get any alert pop up and also i am redirected to the welcome page automatically after i hit 'sign in' i just dont understand what the issue is. Any help would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">

    function login()
        {
        var username = document.getElementById("name");
            var password = document.getElementById("pass");

        if (username.value.trim() == "")
            {
            alert ("please enter a username or password");
            return false;
            }
        else if (password.value.trim() == "")
            {
            alert ("please enter a password");
            return false;

        else
            {
            true;
            }
        }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit = "return validate()" action = "welcome.html">
    <input id= "name" placeholder= "Username" type= "text"/><br><br>
    <input id= "pass" placeholder= "Password" type= "password"/><br><br>
    <button type = "submit">SIGN IN</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a couple typos in here. First, you call `validate()` as the function for `onSubmit` when your function is called `login`. Second, you have `true;` isntead of `return true;` in your else statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on the onsubmit event on the form, you are returning "`validate()`", which is not a real function.

Instead, replace that bit, in the onsubmit attribute, to `onsubmit="return login()"`, since that appears to be your replacement for the validate function.

Secondly though, in the login function itself, for most browsers you also need to call `event.preventDefault()`, right before `return false` (or perhaps instead of). Also, there was a `}` missing in the login function, also causing an error.

The fixed code should be

```js
    function login()
        {
 
        var username = document.getElementById("name");
            var password = document.getElementById("pass");

        if (username.value.trim() == "")
            {
            alert ("please enter a username or password");
           
  event.preventDefault();
         return false;
            }
        else if (password.value.trim() == "")
            {
            alert ("please enter a password");
            
 event.preventDefault();
     return false;
}
        else//this part is also completely extraneous,there's no reason to have it, it should work the same either way 
            {
            true;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit = "return login()" action = "welcome.html">
    <input id= "name" placeholder= "Username" type= "text"/><br><br>
    <input id= "pass" placeholder= "Password" type= "password"/><br><br>
    <button type = "submit">SIGN IN</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working now......i  had ended up changing the name  of the function and forgot to change it in the form however i didnt know about the  event.preventDefault();. so the default pretty much replaces the return